# Using multiple parameters in PHP PDO statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, parameters

I have the following statement set up. I have replaces a long list of columns with * to make this more readable. FYI - I already know that there are questions similar to this. They use SINGLE select statements with a SINGLE parameter. Somehow this is different.

```
$sql = <<<EOM 
SELECT *
    FROM table1
    WHERE StreetName like '%:StreetName_Coml%'
    UNION
    
SELECT *
    FROM table2
    WHERE StreetName like '%:StreetName_Coms%'
    UNION
    
SELECT *
    FROM table3
    WHERE StreetName like '%:StreetName_Farm%'
    UNION
    
SELECT *
    FROM table4
    WHERE StreetName like '%:StreetName_Land%';
EOM;

$p = $db->prepare($sql);

$StreetName = 'tree'
    
$p->bindValue(':StreetName_Coml', $StreetName);
$p->bindValue(':StreetName_Coms', $StreetName);
$p->bindValue(':StreetName_Farm', $StreetName);
$p->bindValue(':StreetName_Land', $StreetName);

$p->execute();

$data = $p->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

The query runs, with no PHP errors. But I am getting no results back. I should be getting back 100's of rows. When I run the same query in my database browser I get 100's of rows. There is something in how the parameters are being bound that is not working.

I have tried the following:

- bindParam instead of bindValue
- moving the '%' from the SQL statement and into $StreetName. So instead of 'tree' it is '%tree%'
- using a CONCAT statement like "WHERE StreetName like CONCAT('%',:StreetName_Land,'%')

and various mix and matching of the above.

What am I missing?

Comment: What you have will not work, but either of your second or third bullet point options should have worked properly (as long as your placeholders were not still in quotes for the second option).

Answer (score 0):

Put the percent signs in the bind, so your SQL is like this, unqouted:

```
WHERE StreetName like :StreetName
```

And then your binds are like this:

```
$p->bindValue(':StreetName', '%' . $StreetName . '%');
```

Comment: OP already said they tried that in their second bullet point

Comment: But it wouldn't work if their placeholders are quoted.

Comment: Yeah, quoted placeholders probably is the problem...

Comment: Although their third bullet point doesn't have quoted placeholders...

Comment: Yeah, <shrug>, hard to say with just a description of what was tried rather that the exact code.

Comment: @Alex Howansky, Nick - Before I delete my account, I wanted to thank you guys for your help. I am tired of seeking help and having my questions closed. It appears that the hostility that this site is known for hasn't gone away.